# cocoa objective c pdfview not loaded

Tags: cocoa

I am a newbie for MAC development, I have a simple Cocoa Application using `NSViewController` where I have a main view and 2 `NSViewController` and dynamically flipping them. I have added `PDFView` on `NSViewController` view to show pdf pages flipping at run time. but my problem when the views are added dynamically then on `PDFView` I can see the pdf page after resizing the window. I tried using `[[pdfViewOutlet1 view] setNeedsDisplay:YES];` for both the views.

```
FirstView *FirstViewController = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:kFirstView bundle:nil];

[FirstViewController setPdfDoc:pdfDoc];
[FirstViewController setPageCnt:pageCnt];
self.myCurrentViewController = FirstViewController;
[[_myCurrentViewController view] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
[transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];

[[_myTargetView animator] addSubview: [_myCurrentViewController view]];
```

and in the `awakeFromNib:` method of first view I have:

```
if(pdfDoc==nil )
        return;

[pdfViewOutlet1 setDisplayMode: kPDFDisplaySinglePageContinuous]; //kPDFDisplaySinglePage or    kPDFDisplayTwoUp;
[pdfViewOutlet1 setDocument:pdfDoc];

NSRect myRect = { { 0,0 }, { 450, 200 } };
[pdfViewOutlet1  setFrame: myRect];

[pdfViewOutlet1 goToPage: [[pdfViewOutlet1 document] pageAtIndex: pageCnt]];
[pdfDoc release];
[[pdfViewOutlet1 view] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

How can I see the pdf pages without resizing the views using mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is solved, i was using setWantsLayer on my Parent view which was creating the issue.